# Angular JS - Pull to refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the pull to refresh plugin for Angular JS. But it is not working. I can see the text, but when I try to pull, nothing happens! I completed all the steps documented on this GitHub page: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh.

Do you have a solution?

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: You seem to have removed the link. Now people which come to this post can no longer see what this was about. Tip: next time use jsFiddle if you don't want people to see the actual url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you currently have (in your ChalengeOverviewCtrl.js):

```
  return $scope.refresh = function() {
    return console.log('test');
  };
```

which doesn't seem correct.  You want to declare the function this way:

```
  $scope.refresh = function() {
    console.log('test');
    return;
  };
```

Not sure if that will fix the issue, but what you have is not right.

Comment: Did this really fix it?  The return value normally shouldn't matter.  Looks like a coffeescript compilation syntax