# AngularJS - Pull down to refresh module not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to implement "pull down to refresh" in Angular. A lot of the JS libraries don't work with Angular, but I found this one:

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh

However, it doesn't work. I see the text "pull down to refresh" on top, so directive is installed properly. But that's it, nothing happens when I scroll down.

```
var feedApp = angular.module("feedApp", ['mgcrea.pullToRefresh']);
....
 <div id="feed-list-content" data-role="content">

    <ul class="feed-list" data-role="listview" pull-to-refresh="onReload()">
      <li ng-repeat="summaryItem in summaryItems | orderBy: 'created':true" class="feed-item">
....
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Same questions here: [Pull to refresh in Angular Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347955/pull-to-refresh-in-angular-js) and here: [Angular JS - Pull to refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579513/angular-js-pull-to-refresh) 
but no solution to my problem.

The onReload method is neither called.

I'm testing on both Android Emulator and Android device. Can't test on iOS, is it caused by Android?

Comment: Does it work on the desktop browser? Did you try with "prestive" sample code from the developer's github? If you run into any specific environment issue (e.g. is it caused by Android), I suggest opening an issue directly with the developer

Comment: I run it inside Cordova, so can't test on the desktop. Tried with Windows Phone as well, doesn't work either.

Comment: I added some console.log inside the the pull-to-refresh.js and both touchmove and touchend are fired...
Hmm, I seem not the only one: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh/issues/9

Comment: Has any one found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I modified this plugin and solved my problem.

Try like this:

```
directive("pullToRefresh", function ($compile, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="pull-to-refresh"><i ng-class="icon[status]"></i>&nbsp;<span ng-bind="text[status]"></span></div><div ng-transclude></div>',
        compile: function compile(elem, attrs, transclude) {
            return function postLink(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {

                var body = $('body');
                var scrollElement = iElem.parent();
                var ptrElement = window.ptr = iElem.children()[0];

                scope.text = {
                    pull: "pull to refresh",
                    release: "release to refresh",
                    loading: "refreshing..."
                };

                scope.icon = {
                    pull: "fa fa-arrow-down",
                    release: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                    loading: "fa fa-refresh fa-spin"
                };

                scope.status = "pull";

                var shouldReload = false;
                var setScrolTop = false;

                var setStatus = function (status) {
                    shouldReload = status === "release";
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.status = status;
                    });
                };

                var touchPoint = 0;

                iElem.bind("touchmove", function (ev) {
                    var top = body.scrollTop();
                    if (touchPoint === 0) touchPoint = ev.touches[0].clientY;
                    var diff = ev.touches[0].clientY - touchPoint;
                    if (diff >= 130) diff = 130;

                    if (diff < 80 && shouldReload) {
                        setStatus("pull");
                        setScrolTop = true;
                    }

                    if (top <= 0) {
                        scrollElement[0].style.marginTop = diff + "px";
                        if (diff > 80 && !shouldReload) setStatus("release");
                    }
                });

                iElem.bind("touchend", function (ev) {
                    if (setScrolTop) {
                        setScrolTop = false;
                        body.scrollTop(0);
                    }
                    if (!shouldReload) {
                        touchPoint = 0;
                        scrollElement[0].style.marginTop = "0px";
                        return;
                    }
                    ptrElement.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 0;
                    ptrElement.style.margin = '0 auto';
                    setStatus("loading");

                    var start = +new Date();
                    $q.when(scope.$eval(iAttrs.pullToRefresh))
                    .then(function () {
                        var elapsed = +new Date() - start;
                        $timeout(function () {
                            body.scrollTop(0);
                            touchPoint = 0;
                            scrollElement[0].style.marginTop = "0px";
                            ptrElement.style.margin = "";
                            ptrElement.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "";
                            scope.status = "pull";
                        }, elapsed < 400 ? 400 - elapsed : 0);
                    });
                });

                scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
                    iElem.unbind("touchmove");
                    iElem.unbind("touchend");
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: editing your solution by replacing ev.touches with ev.originalEvent.touches worked for me. thanks